# Snake using Pygame

Tags: python-3.x, pygame, snake-game

I'd be grateful if you could review my code. Please be as critical towards it as possible and yet indulgent when it comes to asking my first question here.

This is a simple snake game using pygame. I have issues when it comes to classes and not sure if I did it right by putting everything into 1 class and rest as functions. Unfortunately, the best way of learning for me is to use examples :/

Another thing is the snake movement field idea. I have made a tuple list with coordinates across all screen and due to the fact that not all screen is the playable field I have used x and y coordinates to check for example if the snake's head touches the border and should display the game-over message. Any different idea on how to approach it?

Thanks in advance :)

```
import pygame
import sys
import random


class Game(object):

    def __init__(self):
        # Config
        self.fps = 5
        self.resolution = (700, 700)
        self.matrix_table = []
        for i in range(0, 1280, 20):
            for j in range(0, 720, 20):
                self.matrix_table.append((i, j))
        self.snake_parts_position = [629]
        self.snake_movement = 36
        self.new_apple_index = random.randint(185, 1074)
        while self.matrix_table[self.new_apple_index][0] < 100 or self.matrix_table[self.new_apple_index][1] < 100 or \
                self.matrix_table[self.new_apple_index][0] > 580 or self.matrix_table[self.new_apple_index][1] > 580:
            self.new_apple_index = random.randint(185, 1074)
        self.a = self.matrix_table[self.new_apple_index][0]
        self.b = self.matrix_table[self.new_apple_index][1]
        self.font_name = pygame.font.match_font('arial')

        # Init
        pygame.init()
        self.display = pygame.display.set_mode(self.resolution)
        self.fps_clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        self.fps_delta = 0.0

        while True:
            # handle events like player input
            # self.events()

            # ticking
            self.fps_delta += self.fps_clock.tick() / 1000.0
            while self.fps_delta > 1 / self.fps:
                self.events()
                self.movement()
                self.game_over()
                self.eating_apple()
                self.fps_delta -= 1 / self.fps

            # drawing
            self.drawing_fill_flip()

    def drawing_fill_flip(self):
        self.display.fill((0, 0, 0))
        self.draw()
        pygame.display.flip()

    def events(self):
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit(0)
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                sys.exit(0)
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_KP_2:
                if self.snake_movement == -1:
                    pass
                else:
                    self.snake_movement = 1
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_KP_4:
                if self.snake_movement == 36:
                    pass
                else:
                    self.snake_movement = -36
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_KP_6:
                if self.snake_movement == -36:
                    pass
                else:
                    self.snake_movement = 36
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_KP_8:
                if self.snake_movement == 1:
                    pass
                else:
                    self.snake_movement = -1

    def movement(self):
        try:
            if len(self.snake_parts_position) > 1:
                for i in range(len(self.snake_parts_position) - 1, -1, -1):
                    if i > 0:
                        self.snake_parts_position[i] = self.snake_parts_position[i - 1]
                    elif i == 0:
                        self.snake_parts_position[0] += self.snake_movement
            else:
                self.snake_parts_position[0] += self.snake_movement
        except:
            pass

    def draw(self):
        try:
            for i in self.snake_parts_position:
                if i == self.snake_parts_position[0]:
                    pygame.draw.circle(self.display, (255, 255, 0),
                                       (self.matrix_table[i][0] + 10, self.matrix_table[i][1] + 10), 10, 10)
                else:
                    pygame.draw.circle(self.display, (0, 255, 0), (self.matrix_table[i][0] + 10, self.matrix_table[i][1] + 10), 10, 10)
            pygame.draw.circle(self.display, (0, 0, 255), (self.a + 10, self.b + 10), 10, 10)
        except:
            pass

        # dots and brackets
        pygame.draw.rect(self.display, (255, 255, 255), pygame.Rect(110, 110, 1, 1))
        pygame.draw.lines(self.display, (255, 255, 255), True, [(100, 100), (600, 100), (600, 600), (100, 600)])
        for i in range(110, 600, 20):
            for j in range(110, 600, 20):
                pygame.draw.rect(self.display, (255, 255, 255), pygame.Rect(i, j, 1, 1))

    def new_apple(self):
        self.new_apple_index = random.randint(185, 1074)
        while self.matrix_table[self.new_apple_index][0] < 100 or self.matrix_table[self.new_apple_index][1] < 100 or self.matrix_table[self.new_apple_index][0] > 580 or self.matrix_table[self.new_apple_index][1] > 580 or self.new_apple_index in self.snake_parts_position:
            self.new_apple_index = random.randint(185, 1074)
        self.a = self.matrix_table[self.new_apple_index][0]
        self.b = self.matrix_table[self.new_apple_index][1]

    def eating_apple(self):
        if self.snake_parts_position[0] == self.new_apple_index:
            self.snake_parts_position.append(self.snake_parts_position[-1])
            self.new_apple()
            # self.fps += 1

    def game_over(self):
        if self.matrix_table[self.snake_parts_position[0]][0] < 100 or self.matrix_table[self.snake_parts_position[0]][1] < 100 or self.matrix_table[self.snake_parts_position[0]][0] > 580 or self.matrix_table[self.snake_parts_position[0]][1] > 580 :
            self.show_go_screen()
        if len(self.snake_parts_position) != len(set(self.snake_parts_position)):
            self.show_go_screen()

    def draw_text(self, surf, text, size, x, y):
        font = pygame.font.Font(self.font_name, size)
        text_surface = font.render(text, True, (255, 255, 255))
        text_rect = text_surface.get_rect()
        text_rect.midtop = (x, y)
        surf.blit(text_surface, text_rect)

    def show_go_screen(self):
        self.draw_text(self.display, "GAME OVER!", 64, 350, 300)
        self.draw_text(self.display, "Press a key to Continue", 18, 350, 400)
        pygame.display.flip()
        waiting = True
        while waiting:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                    self.__init__()
                    waiting = False


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Game()
```

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Code Review!

### Class definition

One of the very first changes in python 3.x was that you no longer need to explicitly declare class as a subclass of `object`. This declaration is implicit.

```
class Game:
```

### Constants vs attributes

A lot of values in the constructor of your class can be extracted as constant parameters. This will also cover the following point about magic numbers.

### [Magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming))

There are several instances of magic numbers in your code. For eg.

- `random.randint(185, 1074)`
- `self.new_apple_index][0] < 100`
- `self.new_apple_index][0] > 580`
- `self.snake_movement == 36`
- and so on

Replace those values (where do they even come from?) with consistently and properly named constants. This also applies to the colour tuples in your code.

### Execution logic in constructor

As soon as your game class object gets initialised, the game launches and the class loses its purpose of having **so many** declared parameters. The whole thing could have been achieved as a single script.

Having defined attributes inside class, and separating logic for your game, it seems more obvious to me that the game would be launched only when I do `.start()` or `.launch()` or `.run()` or equivalent.

### Redundant conditions/code snippets

At several points in your code, you're doing:

```
event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == <something>
```

If you're interested only in the `KEYDOWN` events, perhaps continue your event polling loop on any other event type, and proceed to compare only for the `event.key` values?

A rewrite would look something like:

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        sys.exit(0)
    if event.type != pygame.KEYDOWN:
        continue
    if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
        sys.exit(0)
    elif event.key == pygame.K_KP_2:
        if self.snake_movement == -1:
            pass
        else:
            self.snake_movement = 1
    elif event.key == pygame.K_KP_4:
        if self.snake_movement == 36:
            pass
        else:
            self.snake_movement = -36
.
.
```

A similar is true for the new apple calculation. You have defined a separate function `new_apple`, yet everything inside is also being done in the constructor.

### sys.exit vs pygame.quit

[pygame docs](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/pygame.html#pygame.quit) suggest using pygame.quit to uninitialise all open pygame modules, and letting the python script exit naturally. You can also find few more discussions around the [same on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11488122/1190388).